# Is it possible to get column name only if has a value?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am having a hard time getting the codes that I need.
The code that I have created can get ALL the column names that I have listed regardless of having a value or not. What I only wanted to happen was to get the column names that has value(1).

[image]

I have this code:

```
    internal static List<string> GetAllRoleTypeFromDatabase()
    {
        List<string> rolelist = new List<string>();
        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(sqliteConnectionMain.connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
        {
            con.Open();
            var _command = con.CreateCommand();
            var queryq = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblUserRoleAccess");
            string commandText = queryq;

            String sSQL;

            sSQL = "SELECT * from tblUserRoleAccess";
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            for (var i = 1; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    rolelist.Add(dr.GetName(i));
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return rolelist;
    }
```

Comment: What is preventing you from just checking each column in your app code to see if it be `NULL` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read a line in the reader (as i understand, there's only one row as a result).
For each column in the row check if its value is `1` (I used `int`, you should use the real type i.e. `bool`, `string` ...):

```
dr.Read();
for (var i = 1; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
{
    if (dr.GetFieldValue<int>(i) == 1)
    {
        rolelist.Add(dr.GetName(i));
    }
}
```